# How can I reference the value of a textbox in a UserForm in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, reference, userform, xlookup

I'm running an xlookup function that i have had previously work on just standard cells, but now i am trying to get it to work from my userform.

Here is my code:

```
Sub bizlookup()
Worksheets("Input").Range("company").Select
ActiveCell = Application.XLookup(Worksheets("Input").Range("phone"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("S:S"), Worksheets("MASTER").Range("U:U"))
End Sub
```

I want to replace the "(Worksheets("Input").Range("phone")" with the value of a TextBox on a userform. How would I reference the value in the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this with the names of your userform and textbox.

```
Worksheets("Input").Range("Phone").Value = UserFormName.TextBoxName.Value
```

Comment: that worked! thank you so much. now i have a new issue as it said that i had a type mismatch, but im trying to figure that out now.